# How to enable a button with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to successfully disable a button with below syntax .

```
$("#list *").attr("disabled", "disabled").off('click');
```

However I also need to enable the button at the end of my function.Any pls help me here how to do this.

Comment: refer to [namespacing](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) for using on and off events, plus why do you need off() when you have disabled attribute? It's not necessary...

Comment: Remove the `.off("click")` so just the `attr("disabled", "disabled")` is there. To re-enable do `removeAttr("disabled")`. That's a horrible selector btw, do something like `$("#list button")`

Comment: `$(..).prop('disabled', false)`

Comment: You should provide a JS fiddle. People have answered your question correctly, but there's an issue outside of what's shown to us. We can help you if you post a fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the attribute to disable the field. Use the property of the DOM element. To disable:

```
$("#list *").prop("disabled", true);
```

To re-enable:

```
$("#list *").prop("disabled", false);
```

Comment: Probably OP has to rebind the click handler as well :D

Answer (score 1):

> The [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method removes event handlers that were attached with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

If you remove the event handler while you are disabling the button, even if you enable it later, it doesn't have the event handler anymore so clicking it won't trigger whatever functionality it had previously. Else you'll have to rebind the event handler as well after enabling it.

Simply disabling the button will prevent it from working, You don't have to remove the `click` handler at all.

You can disable the button using `$("#list *").prop("disabled", true);` and enable it using  `$("#list *").prop("disabled", false);` as [wolfgang Stengel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/826384/wolfgang-stengel) mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25712635/2333214)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `disable` property completely.

`$('#list').removeAttr('disabled');`

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0cjtkwbg/1/)

**Update**
One more thing, setting `disabled` to `true,false,undefined` etc doesn't do anything. You can check this by simply adding a `disable` attribute to an element(without passing it anything) and will keep it disabled forever

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0cjtkwbg/2/)

**Update 2**
As mentioned above, following fiddle describes the affects of passing 'true,false,undefined` in the disable attribute.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/0cjtkwbg/3/)

Comment: *"setting disabled to true,false,undefined etc doesn't do anything"* - totally wrong.

Comment: @TJ why do you think so? I've added a fiddle demonstrating what i meant.

Comment: The statement quoted above is wrong. check the other answers which sets `disabled` to `true` and `false`. BTW `attr` is not the preferred way to alter property values...